# Insert new class using jquery if sub-item has a specific class

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I've generated a menu in Wordpress using `wp_list_pages`

The menu is generated like this:

```
<li class="page_item page-item-11 page_item_has_children">
   <a href="#">News</a>
      <ul class="children">
         <li class="page_item page-item-87 current_page_parent">
            <a href="#">News archive</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
</li>
```

I'm opening up the sub-levels of the menu only when on that section. The problem I have is that some sub-items don't sit within some of the parent levels so I can't just use pure css to target them.

If you look at the code above, the list item has the class "current_page_parent" (which WP is automatically generating), I'm using some css to say `display:none` on the `ul.children`.

How can I use jquery to insert a new class on the `ul.children` if the li within has the class "current_page_parent"?

Or I'm open to a better way if there is one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has)

```
$('ul.children').has('li.current_page_parent').addClass('newclass')
```

or [:has-selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector)

```
$('ul.children:has(li.current_page_parent)').addClass('newclass')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9amCE/)

Comment: I need to add the class to the UL, would it do that?

Comment: @Rob it is adding the class to the `ul`

Comment: Is it possible to do the same check but add the class to the very top li?

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use [**`hasClass()`**](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) method in jQuery

```
if ($('ul.children li').hasClass("current_page_parent")) {
  $('ul').addClass('your new class');
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote it but have now upvoted it as it came in handy for another part of the menu.